# In Cassandra CQL, is there a way to query the size of a collection column type?

Tags: cassandra, cql

We're looking to be able to do something like..

```
select * from User where rewards.size > 0
```

when the schema is

```
create table user (
    id uuid primary key,
    network_id uuid,
    rewards set<uuid>,
    name text   
);
```

Comment: Try this.
select * from User where count(rewards) > '0' ;

Comment: This seems to be the row-count and only valid in a select, not in a where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sadly Cassandra is eager performing very quick reads and on the other hand is not perfectly done supporting collections:
[Get count of elements in Set type column in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334704/get-count-of-elements-in-set-type-column-in-cassandra/23449236#23449236)

> unfortunately the Collections-support even in CQL Driver v2 is not
>   perfect: you may add or delete items in upsert statements. But more on
>   them, like doing an item select, asking for collection item's TTLs or
>   asking for the collection's size, is not supported. So you have to
>
> `resultset: SELECT collection_column FROM ...` 
>   and then take item by
>   `resultset.one()` or `resultset.all()` and get `item.size()` yourself.

What you want to do is adding an indexed column with a counter to count and fast-read the element count. Iff you just want to know whether the collection is not empty you may need an index column with a boolean. The index makes sure you can scan the columns efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

There is a size() method that does just that.. to give an example of how it is used:

```
 select order_id,items.item_id,last_modified from person.ecommerce_order   where size(items.item_id)> 1
```

To explain the query:

**items.item_id** is a list field
.The check is if there are more than one item in the list.

Comment: @Alex Ott, Can you explain, a bit more?

Comment: because your `WHERE` condition doesn't have partition key, so it's sent to all nodes in the cluster, and requires full scan of the data...