# Get count of elements in Set type column in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

how to get the count of elements in a column in Cassandra (cql) which is of Set;
e.g; a Column in a table has value {'9970GBBHVOB61', '9970GBBHVOB62', '9970GBBHVOB6O'} .I want 3 to be returned from the query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604961/how-to-get-size-of-cassandra-list-type-columns-items has an answer to this question

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately the Collections-support even in CQL Driver v2 is not perfect: you may add or delete items in upsert statements. But more on them, like doing an item select, asking for collection item's TTLs or asking for the collection's size, is not supported. So you have to

```
resultset: SELECT collection_column FROM ...
```

and then take item by `resultset.one()` or `resultset.all()` and get `item.size()` yourself. Sorry abut that.

Comment: This seems to be a heavy operation, I might as well maintain another column which stores the count(though this brings redundancy).

Answer (score -2):

To give a very specific answer to your question - *"Column in a table has value {'9970GBBHVOB61', '9970GBBHVOB62', '9970GBBHVOB6O'} .I want 3 to be returned from the query"*

There is a size() method that does just that.. to give an example of how it is used:

```
 select order_id,items.item_id,last_modified from person.ecommerce_order   where size(items.item_id)> 1
```

To explain the query:

**items.item_id** is a list field
.The check is if there are more than one item in the list.