# How to get size of cassandra list type column's items

Tags: list, cassandra, count

cassandra table

```
 seq | keywords            | timestamp
-----+---------------------+---------------
 100 | ['apple', 'banana'] | 1488637750836
```

wanted result

```
 seq | keyword_size
-----+--------------
 100 | 2
```

query

```
select
    seq,
    something(keywords) as keyword_size
from
    t
where
    seq = 100
```

Is there something like function for count column items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no builtin method to do this**

What you can do is get the keywords using a query and get the size using Java or Other programming language from your application backend.

Or Cassandra 2.2 and later allows users to define functions (UDT) that can be applied to data stored in a table as part of a query resul. You can try the below UDF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lsizeof(data list<text>) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS int LANGUAGE java AS 'return data.size();';
```

Now you have the UTF function `lsizeof`, here is how you can get the size of your list using a query like below

```
SELECT seq, lsizeof(keywords) as keyword_size FROM test_list;
```

Output :

```
 seq | keyword_size
-----+--------------
 100 |            2
```

*Note : UDFs (user defined functions) are disabled by default, you can enable it by setting enable_user_defined_functions: true on cassandra.yaml*